# Bash expanding vars

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm running the next command line in Bash shell

```
TZ=Europe/Madrid; MYVAR='{"timestamp": '$(TZ=$TZ date +%s%3N)', "timestampString": "'$(TZ=${TZ} date -Iseconds)'", "data": "Time Zone: '$TZ'   Date ISO8601: '$(TZ=$TZ date -Iseconds)'"}'; curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/add' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "${MYVAR}"
```

The result is:

```
{"_id":"5f577cf2dbf4243e689ced5e","timestamp":1599569138252,"timestampString":"2020-09-08T12:45:38.000Z","data":"Time Zone: Europe/Madrid   Date ISO8601: 2020-09-08T14:45:38+02:00","__v":0}
```

The problem here is that

```
'$(TZ=$TZ date -Iseconds)'
```

is expanded in a different way in "timestampString" and "data". It should be the same string but both are different

I need to use Bash.

In a single command line,
How can expand in both cases as "data"?

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't understand your answer. I think both has the sequence "'$(....)'"

Comment: Och, my bad sorry. What do you mean by "expanded in a different way"? In what "way" and what is different? Is `curl --location...` relevant to the question? I guess It would be easier to see if you would insert some newlines into code snippets.

Comment: "timestampString": "'$(TZ=${TZ} date -Iseconds)'"    and    "data": "Time Zone: '$TZ'   Date ISO8601: '$(TZ=$TZ date -Iseconds)'"}'   I think it's the same sequence @KamilCuk

Comment: Consider using `jq` to generate your JSON: e.g., `MYVAR=$(jq -n '{timestamp: (now|.*100|round), ...}')`

Comment: @chepner I can't. I need to use bash

Comment: Why? Is this a school assignment? Have you been specifically forbidden from using appropriate tools to handle JSON?

Comment: @chepner No, it's not an school assignment. But it's part of the requirements. For the purpose of the problem, it's not important to explain the reasons of this requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date` itself to generate the entire string:

```
MYVAR=$(date +'{"timestamp": %s%3N, "timestampString": "%FT%T.%3NZ", "data": {"Time Zone: '"$TZ"' Date ISO8601: %FT%T%Z"}')
```

Comment: or with printf `printf -v MYVAR '%({...})T'`

Comment: @Ivan I'm not `printf` alone can handle the format the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to split that line like this

```
TZ=Europe/Madrid

MYVAR='{"timestamp": '
MYVAR+="$(TZ=$TZ date +%s%3N), "
MYVAR+='"timestampString": "'
MYVAR+="$(TZ=$TZ date -Iseconds), "
MYVAR+='"data": "Time Zone": '
MYVAR+="$TZ Date ISO8601: $(TZ=$TZ date -Iseconds)"
MYVAR+='"}'

curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/add' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "${MYVAR}"
```

Comment: @J19 yes, but like this it's better to control quotes

Comment: it's mandatory to run in a single command line @Ivan

Comment: @J19 it does **run** "in a single command line" ;) Otherwise you'd need to make sure your "strings" containing expandable vars are NOT single-quoted, but double-quoted to enable expansion...